# Strange errors on building SLN : CS0008 - CS0115

Tags: xml, compiler-errors, manifest, temporary-files

I have a SLN with 4 C# project (the one of them is my mainProgram forms) and a C++ DLL project.

So recently I'm facing this annoying problem, after a PC restart, VC tells me this when I try to compile in Debug or Release mode. I cant figure out what it wants from me. I deleted everything in `%tmp%` reinstalled .NET 4, deleted Debug, Release folder. Nothing worked so far.

> Error 20 Unable to read manifest 'Properties\app.manifest'. Unable to
>   generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0008: Unexpected error
>   reading metadata from file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.XML.dll'
>   -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

After tinkering in the Configuration Manager I produced another error message :

> Error 25 Unable to read manifest 'Properties\app.manifest'. Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0115: Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializer1.CreateWriter()': o suitable method found to override

I've never seen these errors messages before, everything was fine, and this error is come from nowhere, I cant link it to anything I did, I have no clue what is happening.
The only place using XML in my project as far as I know is the NLog logging project, but this error is new so I don't think it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, after deleting everything in temp folder and rebooting the computer, the problem seems to be solved.